# Python: How to parse a XML with dynamic number of children nodes?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, data-processing

I'm parsing a XML dataset and saving it into a mysql database for further processing using the `xml.etree` module in python . There is one node that has variable number of children nodes. For example, lets say:

```
<cars>
   <car type="A" value=35 />
   <car type="B" value=42 />
   <car type="C" value=55 />
   <car type="D" value=23 />
</cars>
```

So, in this example the number of `car` nodes will vary in each document. I know that there can be maximum of `A - H`, so I've created columns from car_A to car_H in my database. I'd normally do a loop like this to get the `value` attribute for each car:

```
for car in root.findall("cars/car"):
    if car.get("type") == "A":
       car_A = car.get("value")
    elif car.get("type") == "B":
       car_B = car.get("value")
    ...
```

But this looks a bit inefficient and I also need to make the car types not present, like car `type=E` to be null. How would I do that without using all the `if..elif` statements and make it more generalizable and efficient? There might be other such nodes with a lot more types of children nodes so manually writing `if...elif` doesn't seem feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `xml.etree` but it's pretty simple if you use `BeautifulSoup`

```
markup = '<cars><car type="A" value=35 /><car type="B" value=42 /><car type="C" value=55 /><car type="D" value=23 /></cars>'
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')
car_dict = {'car_'+car.get('type'): car.get('value') for car in soup.find('cars').findAll('car')}
```

Here's how the `dict` looks like:

```
print car_dict
4: {'car_A': '35', 'car_B': '42', 'car_C': '55', 'car_D': '23'}
```

I have been using `[BeautifulSoup][1]` and it serves the best for which it was build for! + documentation is extensive !

Edit:
If you want it using `xml.etree` only I suggest you use a similar approach i.e. using a dictionary:

```
car_dict = {}
for car in root.findall("cars/car"):
    car_dict.update({'car_'+car.get("type"): car.get("value")})
```

or if you want to update local variable instead of creating a separate dictionary, try this(I guess this is exactly what you wanted in the first place):

```
car_dict = {}
for car in root.findall("cars/car"):
    locals().update({'car_'+car.get("type"): car.get("value")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to store all the data in a dict, using `child.attrib` method?

```py
xml_str = '''
<cars>
    <car type="A" value="32"/>
    <car type="B" value="42"/>
    <car type="C" value="55"/>
    <car type="D" value="23"/>
</cars>
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

cars = {}
for child in root:
    cars[child.attrib['type']] = child.attrib['value']
```

Output is

`{ 'A': 32, 'B': 42, 'C': 55, 'D': 23 }`

Then you can just process the dict, which might be easier

Answer (score 0):

```
cars={}
for car in root.findall("cars/car"):
    car_type="car_"+car.get("type")
    cars[car_type]=car.get("value")
```

also if you have predefined variable that use them in other places (in your code) , you can use this line to make variable (or overwrite values) from dictionary keys :

`locals().update(cars)`

then

```
car_A
```

is a variable if not defined previously (or has new value if defined).